# Remove top and bottom image spacing in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

In Outlook Desktop apps (2010 and 2013) there's an extra gap on images at top and bottom:
[image]

Maybe the problem is easier to recognize if the content is marked:
[image]

It looks like some margin and padding stuff, but that did not work. I tried different hacks/solutions too (e.g. set line-height on table cell, remove whitespaces in table cell, remove surrounding div, set vspace and hspace on image, set `display: block` for image,...), but without an effect. The HTML looks like:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="311" valign="top" class="nopadding imagecell" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,HelveticaNeue,Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
                <div class="imagewrap" style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                    <img align="left" src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="311" height="234" alt="" style="margin: 0;">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="10" style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,HelveticaNeue,Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
                    &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="background padding" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; background-color: #ececed; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,HelveticaNeue,Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
                <h1 style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,HelveticaNeue,Calibri,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 19px; font-weight: normal; color: #51ae32; margin: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">PhD-Program erstmals ausgezeichnet</h1>
                <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Andipsun daereicit fugit aut quunt volupta tibus. Abore doluptu reptatiumet ad mag- nam fugit dolupturepe nissunt. El illitateni nonecatem rae odi ut dest que asperro vi- tatia ectorem dit laut optas et nonecatem rae. El illitateni nonecatem rae odi ut dest que asperro vitatia ectorem dit laut optas et nonecatem rae. <a href="/" style="color: #51ae32;">Weiterlesen</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The rendering should be like in other clients or browsers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Have you included any CSS resets in the `<head>` of the email for `<table>`s and `<td>`s?** Here is some code from the reset I use that focuses on resetting the padding and borders in `<table>`s (does not have to be inlined):

```
<head>
    <style>
        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto; 
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Here is the [full CSS reset I use for emails](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/cerberus-fluid.html).

**EDIT**

Concerning images, add a `display: block;` inline to each image to negate any extra space beneath the image.

```
<img style="margin: 0; display: block;" align="left" src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="311" height="234" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this already, but this doesn't solve the problem either. I think lspace and rspace stands vor vertical spaces, whereas I have to deal with a horizontal spacing problem only in conjunction if image and text are positioned next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and discovered a solution.

Remove the padding from the text's parent `<td>`, nest another table within this `<td>` and add the padding back to the child `<td>`.

So, to simplify your example:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0">
                <div>
                    <img align="left" src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="311" height="234" alt="" style="margin: 0;">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="10">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; background-color: #ececed;">
                <h1>PhD-Program erstmals ausgezeichnet</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Would become:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0">
                <div>
                    <img align="left" src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="311" height="234" alt="" style="margin: 0;">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="10">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: #ececed;">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                                <h1>PhD-Program erstmals ausgezeichnet</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```